# Facebook Messenger Bot only working for me (developer)

Tags: node.js, facebook, bots, facebook-messenger, chatbot

Hi I got my bot approved and the app is live to the public, but it only sends responses to me. Please help. Im a beginner and not sure what's wrong

Update: Please see [Messenger Bot Fails to Respond](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38354567/messenger-bot-fails-to-respond/)

Comment: Please don't just down vote, help solve this

Comment: Without any code example we can't help. You should share the questionable parts in here and not just ask a general question.

Comment: It really isn't an issue with the code. The code works fine . I believe I had something to do with how to setup the bot on Facebook

Comment: How can you be so sure?

Comment: I know for a fact because it only works for people I specify in the Role section and not the public. The code doesn't not specify any sort of privileges . Also, if I were something to do with the code,then every user , including me and the ones I specified in the roles, would have the same issue

Comment: I am having the same problem, did you happen to get the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a bit late but perhaps this will help.  I just got my bot approved today.  In the App Review panel, I now see that 'pages_messaging' is enabled.  Also, under the 'Messenger->Setting' I see 'Bot Ratings'. The bot appears to be open to the world as several people have accessed it.

http://messenger/t/dynamicmemorysolutions

Answer (score 0):

please verify if your app is available to the general public.

Follow these steps:

1. Login to your facebook developer console.
2. In **Basic settings** provide an email.
3. In **App Review** switch to **YES** (general public)

In **Roles** section you can also define test users in order to verify that your Bot is working as expected.

Regards

Comment: I've done all this. It works only for the people I specify in the Roles section and not for the public